# Reading integers from a file c++

Tags: c++, file-io, compression, lzw

I implemented an LZW compressor which encodes the strings into integers with the help of a hash function. I stored the coded string in a text file. Now I need to decompress the same code. I am confused how to differentiate between a two digit integer and a single digit integer while reading from the text file.

For example, my dictionary is:

```
0  c 
1  bba
3  aa
5  ac
7  bb
8  aab
9  a
10 b
```

and so on.

Now, suppose I encoded a string 'aaabbbac' into "9 3 10 7 9 0" which gets stored in the text file as 9310790. How to differentiate between 0, 1 and 10 while reading from a file?

Comment: If they are stored exactly like that (not as binary with each as a byte), then you can't differentiate without a separator character.

Comment: Why dont you store them as actual integers (not a string representing an integer)

Comment: Normally in a compression program you don't write text and don't write binary bytes, you write a stream of *bits* (your code boundaries do not fall on byte boundaries). Bit-width of the next value to read is determined by the decoder state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some options:

- Store them in binary format rather than text format. That might be a little challenge to read and write but it might be worthy the learning. The problem is if you want to visualize the numbers using a text editor but you can find some tool to visualize binary files. Assuming 2 bytes per integer (type short), your example would be in hexa (not considering endian): 00 09 00 03 00 0a 00 07 00 09 00 00
- Store them with fixed length per number. Example: printf("%03d", number) will always create numbers with 3 digits. Your example would be: 009003010007009000
- Use a comma or semi-colon separator: 9,3,10,7,9,0